# Need to pass model value on Read action on DropDownFor in a popup editor template

Tags: telerik

I have a Telerik grid (MVC) configured with a popup editor on the grid rows.  In the editor template, I have a DropDownFor list in addition to textboxes displaying the grid row values.  This all works.

The DropDownFor has a Read action and I need to pass the model value to the controller to set the selected value.  **The model value is not recognized.**

Here is the DropDownFor:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.OuterDiameter)
    .Name("OuterDiameter")
    .DataValueField("Text")
    .DataTextField("Value")
    .DataSource(ds =>
     {
       ds.Read(read =>
        {
          read.Action("GetPipeOD", "Materials", new { od = m.OuterDiameter });
         });
      })
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style="width:100px"})

 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass adicional parameter using a JavaScript funcion.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.OuterDiameter)
.Name("OuterDiameter")
.DataValueField("Text")
.DataTextField("Value")
.DataSource(ds =>
 {
   ds.Read(read =>
    {
      read.Action("GetPipeOD", "Materials").Data("getParameter");
     });
  })
  .HtmlAttributes(new { style="width:100px"})
```

)

```
<script>
    function getParameter() {
        return od: '@Model.Parameter' 
       //Or what do you need...
    }
</script>
```